# How is the list of available API levels determined?

Tags: android, android-studio

When designing a layout in Android Studio, in Preview window there is an option to pick the API level for which the preview would be rendered. I thought that this list matches Platform SDK installed. But doesn't. I have installed a couple of SDKs, but for different xml files in a single project, I have different lists of available API levels. For some it is just a single entry, like 23 in the picture. So how can I make sure that a particular API level is available for the Preview?

[image]

Comment: isn't it all versions your project supports? `minSdkVersion` to `compileSdkVersion`

Comment: No. minSdkVersion is 17, compileSdkVersion is 19, targetSdkVersion is 19.

Comment: for me it's 21 to 24 (`min` to `compile`). must be coincidence, then :-)

Comment: What do you mean by 'coincidence'? min is 17, compile is 19 - both are installed and they are not available. Besides, other xmls in this project present correctly all available SDK, so there must be sth else which affects this list, rather than build.gradle settings.

Comment: must be coincidence that for me its exactly the minimum up to the compile version _for me_